# Fastest method of finding matlab function paramater types?

Tags: matlab

I'm working on translating a large repository that has been prototyped with MATLAB , over to C++.
Of course, C++ wants to know the exact parameter type for each I/O to the function. Trouble is, I'm finding it difficult to track down each type in MATLAB as they are not always attached to an example script that passes values.

As a simple example, let's say I have the following in my *exampleFunction.m* file:

```
[rangeEnd, rangeStart, elevation] = exampleFunction [t, position1, position2, height1, height2]
```

What is the best method for finding the parameter types being passed to this function if I cannot easily find an example script that makes a call to 'exampleFunction'? I hope this question makes enough sense, feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: You cannot know what values are passed to the function if you don't have an example of the code that calls the function. What is more, each place the function is called could pass different data types and different number of parameters. The best you can do is set a breakpoint entering the function, and run code until the breakpoint is tripped, then examine the value of the variables in the input argument list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed that is what I've been trying to do, setting a breakpoint at the function. In most instances, I'm just having difficulty finding examples that actually call that particular function which really slows me down.

Comment: And of course the documentation sucks and therefore it doesn't clarify how the function should be called? :) I'm sorry.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Exactly... team writing the matlab code is used to the flexibility when declaring functions. Therefore it was never documented.

Comment: You could just set everything to `double`, which is the default for all MATLAB numbers unless they are specifically typed. May not be particularly efficient, but might be worth trying?

Comment: There is no automatic ways to know the expected type but when translating the code of the function itself the operations done on the variable should give you some clues for most types. The most cryptic type will be cell arrays, as they could contain absolutely anything.

Comment: If you want to find a script which call a specific function, use another tool than Matlab. In some IDE you often have the option to "find all references" to a function or symbol. Since it is not available in Matlab, I often use [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). It has a search function which can search for the name of your function in a whole set of folder and subfolder. It can be litteral or regex, and it's pretty fast. It will report every line and every file where your function name is mentionned. You can then go and check how it is called.

Comment: @Hoki Thank you. Does notepad++ do something ctrl + shift + f in matlab cannot do?

Comment: Yes it's exactly the function I use: [ctrl]+[shift]+[F]. In the dialog box you can set the parent folder of you project or repository and include the subfolders from there.